# Using enums in Java

Tags: java, enums

Constants given in the following `enum`,

```
enum StringConstatns {
    ONE {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "One";
            }
        },

    TWO {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Two";
            }
        }
}

public final class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(StringConstatns.ONE + " : " + StringConstatns.TWO);
    }
}
```

can be accessed just like `StringConstatns.ONE` and `StringConstatns.TWO` as shown in the `main()` method.

---

I have the following `enum` representing an `int` constant(s).

```
public enum IntegerConstants
{
    MAX_PAGE_SIZE(50);
    private final int value;

    private IntegerConstants(int con) {
        this.value = con;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This requires accessing the constant value like `IntegerConstants.MAX_PAGE_SIZE.getValue()`.

Can this `enum` be modified somehow in a way that `value` can be accessed just like `IntegerConstants.MAX_PAGE_SIZE` as shown in the first case?

Comment: `toString()` is called automatically everytime you concatenate an object in a string, that's why you don't need to call it explicitly.

Comment: You can add a `toString()` to your `IntegerConstants` but it will return as string of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot. You have to call:

```
IntegerConstants.MAX_PAGE_SIZE.getValue()
```

If you really want a shortcut, you could define a constant somewhere like this:

```
public class RealConstants {
    final public static int MAX_PAGE_SIZE = 50;
}
public enum IntegerConstants
{
    MAX_PAGE_SIZE(RealConstants.MAX_PAGE_SIZE);//reuse the constant
    private final int value;

    private IntegerConstants(int con) {
        this.value = con;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to work because your first example does implicit calls to `.toString()` when you concatenate them with `+`, whereas there is no implicit conversion to `int` which is needed for your second example.

You could define them as `static final` fields, this does exactly what you are searching for:

```
public class IntegerConstants {
    public static final int MAX_PAGE_SIZE = 50;
}
```